# Django attach a file to FileField encoding error

Tags: python, django, file-upload, encoding

Would like to attach a file from a View to a Model in Django 1.8. It is working with a txt file but not with pdf or excel. I am getting a 'ascii' codec can't decode, exception type: UnicodeDecodeError. Do I need to set the encoding in Django or am I using "open" wrong?

Exception Value:
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb9 in position 11: ordinal not in range(128)

Python Version: 3.5.2

views.py

```
local_file = open('/var/www/taras/portal/portal1987/media/uploads/APP2017.xlsx',  'r')
application =  Application.objects.get(pk=pk)
application.report_excel_doc.save('APPL2017_New.xlsx', File(local_file))
```

models.py

```
report_excel_doc = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Try opening the file using binary mode `open('/var/www/taras/portal/portal1987/media/uploads/APP2017.xlsx',  'rb')`

Comment: Thank you, reading in binary mode resolves the encoding issue. And attaches the file.